# Is using chocolate instead of royal icing for a gingerbread house more difficult?

Tags: chocolate, icing, gingerbread

[Heston Blumenthal's recipe](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/hestons-feasts/articles/all/heston-style-gingerbread-house-recipe) states royal icing or melted chocolate to build his gingerbread house.

Until now I've used an eggless substitute for royal icing with adequate results, although it's trickier. Am I asking for even more trouble with the chocolate?

I have some experience dipping truffles in tempered chocolate. I won't burn or tighten the chocolate, but I don't know if it will hold up.

Tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just went for it by following directions here: 
http://www.taste.com.au/good+taste/article/good+times/make+a+gingerbread+house,635

I will say that "Set aside for 3-5 minutes. The chocolate sets quickly" was very optimistic.
Needed to balance roof on supports til chocolate was hard -an hour! Yes, it cooled quickly but did not become hard til then. Used 50% dark chocolate (no milk)

About as tricky in the end as eggless icing but less messy, funnily enough. Seems secure enough now. My gingerbread sections are already absorbing some room moisture so we shall see how the whole thing holds up...

Comment: After tearing the house apart the 12th day of Christmas, choc was yummy addition. really held up fine. next time will coat the backsides of all pieces first guaranteeing no leftovers after demolition

Answer (score 2):

A light touch of melted chocolate on the roof never hurt anyone. I already tried and the house holds up very well!

Comment: on the roof or as cement holding roof together? wanting to replace the icing not decorate

Comment: I don't think it would hold as cement but as icing it's awesome! Gives that taste royal icing wouldn't give you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a thick simple syrup to reattach the limbs of some broken gingerbread men (I put a thick coat on both ends, pressed firmly together, then let sit to harden).  I also make frosting with just powdered sugar and warm water; it doesn't have the same cementing ability as the syrup did, however.  In my experience, melted chocolate has very little cementing ability.  Good luck! :)

Comment: I'd love to hear how that works out!  I've never made a gingerbread house, and your question made me want to try, so I just found his recipe online.. :)

Comment: 24hrs and still standing. Made playdough of leftover store-bought white frosting warmed and plenty of powder sugar kneaded in: just the ticket for kids to attach sweets. Can be peeled off in the first minutes to rearrange before it hardens. Also used same simple piping icing as you for details like icicles http://www.flickr.com/photos/ellienickpat/DSC05076-001